# Weekly Digest Email to Group (Mailing List)

Tags: civimail, templates

What route would one take to creating an automated weekly digest for an existing mailing list group? Can this be done with a scheduled reminder along with some code in a template file somewhere? I am running Drupal and am wondering if maybe a scheduled reminder email that has some code to grab the result from a view to plop into the email body might work?

Answer (score 1):

As a partial answer, we did some work to enable a View to be pulled in to a civimail as a token. The code is [here](https://github.com/eileenmcnaughton/civicrm_views_token) but could do with some further improvements and is untested afaik in respect of Scheduled Reminders.